# How to point to the address where the php is

Tags: php, html, url-routing

Hello I`m trying to echo the address where my php is so for example this is my address:

http://domain.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=20_27&product_id=41

I want a php that returns "domain.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=20_27&product_id=41"

I`ve got thus far to domain.com/index.php using :

```
<?php
$address = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$address1 = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$address3 = "http://$adres$adres1";
$address4 = $adres3;
$address5 = $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"];

echo "$address4"; ?>
```

Can someone pls hlp ?
thx

Comment: you're looking for QUERY_STRING

Comment: Add a line `print_r($_SERVER);` and you can find it all out yourself.

Comment: So... you want the url without `http://` ?

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Comment: @greut post a answer with ehat you said and complet so I can mark it

Comment: It seems like you are making typos you set things as $address and call them as $adres

Comment: opencart facebook like button insertion :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $url;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's

```
$address = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

To find out stuff like this is general create a php file with that content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Open it in your browser and scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Chronical srry butt that will not suffys

Comment: Why do you think so? This will give you exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @John the horn - be more specific - why doesn't this work? (it's the same as the answer I wrote below, and it works for me (tested) with domain, file, and any query string variables.